# Javascript Load json data to downdrop options if other dropdown correlates

Tags: javascript, html

so I have some json data that looks like this:

```
 var jsondata  = [{"country": "australia", "service": ["nextdoor", "clubhouse", "farpost", "mylavash", "burger-king", "zolushka", "zdorov"]}]
 let decodedJson = JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

And when the country australia has been selected from the dropdown with the id country, I would like update all of the options of the dropdown with the id service, with all of the services from the jsondata that is from australia.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var jsondata  =  var jsondata  = [{"country": "australia", "service": ["nextdoor", "clubhouse", "farpost", "mylavash", "burger-king", "zolushka", "zdorov"]}]
    let decodedJson = JSON.parse(jsondata);
    //if country dropdown is selected then update service dropdown with services from decodedJson
    $("#country").change(function() {
        var country = $("#country option:selected").val();
        var services = decodedJson[country]["service"];
        var serviceSelect = document.getElementById('service');
        serviceSelect.innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = services[i];
            opt.innerHTML = services[i];
            serviceSelect.appendChild(opt);
        }
    });
</script>
<html>
    <body>
        <select id="country">
            <option value="0">usa-voip</option>
        </select>
        <select id="service">
            <option value="0">nextdoor</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: First, you don't have JSON. You have a javascript array. Have you looked at your console for errors? using JSON.parse to parse a javascript array should have generated an error

Comment: The first line of code is repeating the `var` declaration, which is probably a syntax error.  The second line of code is trying to parse JSON which isn't actually JSON, which would also produce an error.  Your very first debugging step here should be to open your browser's debugging tools and check the console for errors, and address those specific errors.  *Edit:* Additionally, why is the `<script>` element *before* the entire `<html>` element?  Move it to just before `</body>`.

Comment: If something isn't working, always, always, always check the console. Looking at the code and guessing what the issue is is way harder than looking at the log and getting an actual error to go off of.

Comment: After you fix the actual errors, you will notice that your country change doesn't work. That is probably because there is only one item in it. This could be a problem with copying and pasting here and not wanting to paste every country option though.

Comment: the error is ok.html:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined @imvain2

Comment: @bigboss $ is not defined just means you haven't included jquery or the right version (some reference jQuery instead)

Comment: @imvain2 now I'm not getting any error in the console, but it's still not working

Comment: @bigboss: Please update the question to a [mcve] which demonstrates the current problem you are trying to solve.  As it stands, the code shown in the question has a multitude of problems which have been pointed out in comments, which produce specific errors that you can observe on the browser console, and some of which amount of little more than typos.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure why you've placed an `object` inside of an `array`, but if we assume you're getting data from a database you'd still get a `SyntaxError` because you can't pass an `object` into `JSON.parse`, it's supposed to take a `string`.

For this to be runnable at all you'd have to format your data in one of the following ways:

1. wrap the contents of the `array` in quotes to make it a `string`, and then retrieve the first index.

```js
var jsondata = '[{ "country": "australia", "service": ["nextdoor", "clubhouse", "farpost", "mylavash", "burger-king", "zolushka", "zdorov"] }]'
let decodedJson = JSON.parse(jsondata)[0];
```

2. remove the `JSON.parse` call

```js
var jsondata = [{ "country": "australia", "service": ["nextdoor", "clubhouse", "farpost", "mylavash", "burger-king", "zolushka", "zdorov"] }]
let decodedJson = jsondata[0];
```

This is clearly a `jQuery` implementation (I think you should note that when you write your question)

Your version of this code won't trigger a change event because the `country` `select` element doesn't have any `options` to *change to*. You should add the option before your event listener.

```js
var countrySelect = document.getElementById('country');
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = decodedJson['country'];
opt.innerHTML = decodedJson['country'];
countrySelect.appendChild(opt);
```

To prevent problems with `jQuery` in any further code you should wrap the whole thing in a [jQuery ready listener](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Your `object` query to find a service will also resolve to `undefined`.

You're essentially calling for `decodedJson['australia']['service']` when your object is

```json
{ 
"country": "australia",
"service": ["nextdoor", "clubhouse", "farpost", "mylavash", "burger-king", "zolushka", "zdorov"]
}
```

To get the services you need to make a query like `decodedJson['service']`

With these changes, the code will execute whenever *anything* is selected from the `country` `select` element. In your post you mentioned you only want it to render the dropdown options if `australia` is selected, so I'd suggest wrapping the whole `option` render in a conditional after the `options` are reset.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var jsondata = [{ "country": "australia", "service": ["nextdoor", "clubhouse", "farpost", "mylavash", "burger-king", "zolushka", "zdorov"] }]
        let decodedJson = jsondata[0];

        //if country dropdown is selected then update service dropdown with services from decodedJson
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var countrySelect = document.getElementById('country');
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = decodedJson['country'];
            opt.innerHTML = decodedJson['country'];
            countrySelect.appendChild(opt);

            $("#country").change(function () {
                var country = $("#country option:selected").val();
                var services = decodedJson["service"];
                var serviceSelect = document.getElementById('service');
                serviceSelect.innerHTML = "";
                if (country === 'australia') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
                        var opt = document.createElement('option');
                        opt.value = services[i];
                        opt.innerHTML = services[i];
                        serviceSelect.appendChild(opt);
                    }
                }

            });
        })

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="country">
        <option value="0">usa-voip</option>
    </select>
    <select id="service">
        <option value="0">nextdoor</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```